# How to invoke the job from one slave(server) to another slave(server) in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Please, can you advise as I am planning to invoke a job that is on different server. For example:

Slave1 server1: deploy job

Slave2 server2: build job

I want build job trigger the deploy job. Any suggestion, please

Comment: You man you have the two Jobs in 2 different Jenkins servers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run two Jobs in the same Jenkins server. Your Pipeline should look something like below. Here from build Job you can call the Deploy Job.

**Build Job**

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'server2' } 
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                build job: 'DeployJobName'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Deploy Job**

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'server1' } 
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                // Deploy something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

If you want to trigger a Job in a different Jenkins server, you can use a Plugin like [RemoteTriggerPlugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) or simply using the Jenkins API.

```
curl http://serer1:8080/job/DeployJobName/build?token=YOUR_REMOTE_TRIGGER_TOKEN
```

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'server2' } 
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'curl http://server1:8080/job/DeployJobName/build?token=YOUR_REMOTE_TRIGGER_TOKEN'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my deploy job is on different jenkin server

Comment: Thanks, i will try this in my jenkinsfile and will update you so it would be something like :  pipeline {
    agent { label 'server1' } 
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps { script{
                curl http://serer1:8080/job/DeployJobName/build?token=YOUR_REMOTE_TRIGGER_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Willingtolearn added a sample pipeline.

Comment: I am getting this error java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from server-test/10.22.16.15:61442
  at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1788)
  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
  at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:998)